# In Flutter when I write Command "flutter build apk" I have error " Error: No pubspec.yaml file found

Tags: flutter

```
Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.
Do not run this command from the root of your git clone of Flutter.
```

Please note that I have executed the same project previously more than once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the wrong folder in the command prompt..navigate to the root directory of your project in which the `pubspec.yaml` is placed.

Comment: Which operating system you are using?

Comment: i,m using android studio

Comment: which operating system?not software

Comment: Sorry , windows 10

Comment: just open the terminal in the bottom of android studio and check wether the path name is matching with your project name or not....if not open a new window there.